# Missing dependencies warning React doesn\t show up

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, vscode-extensions

I have an issue where the missing dependencies warning doesn't show up any longer for `useEffect` in React. I am using VS Code if that matters.

Does anyone know what could be the cause for this, as right now I don't even know where to start debugging.

Comment: Possibly something wrong with ESLint, the Typescript server, or both. What package manager are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Please install both the [Error lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens) and [Microsoft ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint). It worked for me.

I hope this works for you also.

Comment: thanks EsLint extension solve my problem

Comment: This did not work for me. I have both extensions installed with `plugin:react-hooks/recommended` set up in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code, press `Ctrl + Shift + P` to bring the command prompt, and run ESLint: Show Output Channel. If ESLint is missing certain React plugins, it will tell you so.

It might also be something wrong with VS Code's TS server. It is the thing that is checking for dependencies, amongst other things. Open the terminal (`Ctrl + '`), select the Output tab, and on the right hand side select Typescript from the dropdown menu.

If you are using Yarn v3, you need to install eslint and typescript as dev dependencies, then run `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` and switch VS Code to the workspace version of Typescript (the prompt for that will show in a popup).

Answer (score 0):

your problem is related with eslint.

check your code to see is there any line of code like this?

```
 // eslint-disable-next-line
```

or this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

if yes, delete it.

another cause can be the **.eslintignore** file.
check if there is this **.eslintignore** file exists on your project, delete it should solve your problem

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work in any project, so it is not related to one particular project. 

I have installed eslint globally, I have eslint extension for VSCode

Comment: fixed it by adding "plugin:react-hooks/recommended" to eslint file. 

Is there a way to make this global so I do not have to add it for each project?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using [React Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jawandarajbir.react-vscode-extension-pack) where some of included extension was already installed in my Vs Code. Then I uninstalled all included extension, after that again install React Extension Pack, and automatically removed all issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may have disabled the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` eslint rule or extended an eslint ruleset which disables it. Make sure that the follow line is absent in any of the eslint configurations used:

`'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'off'`

Answer (score 0):

VSCode eslint will not work as expected if one of your `.eslintrc` configuration rules has a wrong configuration.

For example:

```json
{
  ...
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": false, // <---- this will turn off the warning
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  },
  ...
}
```

and if you change '**false**' into '**off**' then the error will be shown up

```json
{
  ...
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off", // <---- replace false into off
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating the VS Code. ESLint became incompatible with my old VS Code version.